# Why logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler prints unknown characters?

Tags: python, django, logging, handler, formatter

I want to store django logs in a file on disk. So I'm using the following dictConfig. But when I check my log file, I see there are some unknown characters printed! What's the problem?

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,


    'formatters': {
        'django.server': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.ServerFormatter',
            'format': '[{server_time}] {message}',
            'style': '{',
        }
    },


    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
    },


    'handlers': {
        'django.server': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'django.server',
        },

        'logfile': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            # 'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'formatter': 'django.server',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'carpooling.log'),
            'maxBytes': 50 * 2**20,  # 50MB
            'backupCount': 3,
        },

        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'include_html': True,
        },

        'null': {
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
    },


    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },

        'django.server': {
            'handlers': ['django.server', 'mail_admins', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

When I request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` on my browser, I see the `[21/Aug/2019 18:28:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1868` on console but in the log file the record is as follows: `[21/Aug/2019 18:28:17] [m[m[m"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1868[0m[0m[0m`

Comment: What versions of python and django are you using?

Comment: @Xukrao django 2.2.2

Comment: How exactly do you view the log files? Have you tried opening the log files with different reader applications to see if there's any difference?